# Error in lapply function to data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame "df" with several character columns. I need to set a limits of length depend on the max length of each char-column.

I tried to do:

```
SetOraStrLength <- function(DfColumn){

  MaxStrLength <- as.integer(0)

  if (typeof(DfColumn) == "character")
  {
    MaxStrLength <- max(nchar(DfColumn, allowNA = FALSE))
    if (MaxStrLength > 0 & MaxStrLength <= 25){
      attr(DfColumn, "ora.encoding") <- "UTF-8"
      attr(DfColumn, "ora.maxlength") <- 25
    } else if (MaxStrLength > 25 & MaxStrLength <= 50) {
      attr(DfColumn, "ora.encoding") <- "UTF-8"
      attr(DfColumn, "ora.maxlength") <- 50
    } else if (MaxStrLength > 50 & MaxStrLength <= 150) {
      attr(DfColumn, "ora.encoding") <- "UTF-8"
      attr(DfColumn, "ora.maxlength") <- 150
    } else {
      attr(DfColumn, "ora.encoding") <- "UTF-8"
      attr(DfColumn, "ora.maxlength") <- 255
    }
  }

}
```

And then:

```
lapply(df, SetOraStrLength)
```

Finally, I have error:

> Error in if (MaxStrLength > 0 & MaxStrLength <= 25) { :    missing
>   value where TRUE/FALSE needed Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)

What is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps `MaxStrLength` is `NA`? Why not print it and see what it is? Also, here you might want `&&` rather than `&`.

Comment: Maybe you want to also see `keepNA = FALSE` in `nchar`? Or maybe just omit `NA` values from the column before taking the `nchar`? You also might find the `cut` function nicer than all these hand-coded intervals.

Comment: Lastly, I'd recommend that your function `return` something at the end. Especially if the column is not a character, it's not at all clear what the function will return. Just add a `return(DFColumn)` as the last line.

Comment: Also, it is recommended that you test the class of an object with `inherits(DfColumn, "character")`.

Comment: Thank you guys! I've found column with all NA values. That was a problem.